# iTextsharp.dll not working in vs 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

i want to use/add iTextsharp dll(version 5.5) to my website(Asp.net 3.5 using C#)but On add reference
     Right Click**Solution Explore**> **Add Reference** >browse and Select **DLL**
      and after all when i compile my Website it shows Compile time  Error **The type or namespace name 'iTextSharp' could not be found** in vs 2008

but it works fine on vs 2010 with Same procedure to add DLL with same DLL version 5.5

Comment: Do you have same target architecture as that compiled DLL?

Comment: vs2008 Target Framwork 3.5 and vs2010 Target Framwork 4.0 but also when i change vs2010 Target Framwork 4.0 to 3.5 it show the same error as in vs 2008

Comment: Have you tried compiling iTextSharp against your target framework?

Comment: @GauravKaushik : I'm not talking about target framework, but architecture. x86 or x64